# Differentiating real and synthesized GetLastInputInfo for Windows application idle time detection

Tags: winapi

I am working on a Windows desktop application that has a need to determine the user's session idle time:

```
GetTickCount() - GetLastInputInfo's LASTINPUTINFO.dwTime
```

GetLastInputInfo doesn't seems to distinguish between real user input events and events that are synthesized via SendInput, keybd_event or mouse_event. This is affecting one user's machine because they have a piece of software calling one of these functions.

2 questions:

1. Do I have any means in a desktop application to differentiate between real and synthesized user input events?
2. Do I have any means ([ETW?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) to diagnose what software is calling a function to synthesize user input events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have any means in a desktop application to differentiate between real and synthesized user input events?

Yes. You can set up a low-level keyboard and mouse [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx). The [LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) receives a [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx), whose *flags* field contains `LLKHF_INJECTED` or `LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` for input that is generated using [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) or [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx).

Similarly, the [LowLevelMouseProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx) is passed a [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx), whose *flags* field contains `LLMHF_INJECTED` or `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` for synthesized input.

> Do I have any means (ETW?) to diagnose what software is calling a function to synthesize user input events?

As far as I know, injected input events don't carry any information, which process they originated from.

Comment: In the latter case, you would have to manually hook `SendInput()`/`keybd_event()`/`mouse_event()` in every running process.