# GetLastInputInfo changes with no input

Tags: winapi

I'm using [GetLastInputInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) to track user idle time in a desktop mixed mode C++ / C# application.

On one user's machine, GetLastInputInfo will advance its time, even when I register no low level keyboard or mouse input via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41829588/3794464) method.

The user (a coworker so I have access to the machine) runs Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga.

Below is sample output from my program to poll on GetLastInputInfo and display low level mouse and keyboard events:

```
Mouse: 57 wParam:512 flags:0 pt:1366,57 14750640 12:06:37.0864968
Mouse: 58 wParam:512 flags:0 pt:1366,60 14750656 12:06:37.0964981
Mouse: 59 wParam:512 flags:0 pt:1365,60 14750671 12:06:37.1064994
GetLastInputInfo 60 gliiRet:True cbSize:8 dwTime:14750671 12:06:37.2465354
GetLastInputInfo 61 gliiRet:True cbSize:8 dwTime:15063750 12:11:50.2038808
```

which implies that mouse events at 12:06:37.1064994 caused GetLastInputInfo #60 at 12:06:37.2465354, but between 12:06:37.2465354 and 12:11:50.2038808, no mouse or keyboard user input events occurred, but still GetLastInputInfo advanced to a new dwTime.

I'd like to determine the root cause of this problem. Is this a faulty device driver? Are there other trappable user input events that affect GetLastInputInfo that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the screensaver affected by this phantom input?

Comment: Low-level keyboard hooks can filter input, preventing your hook procedure from ever seeing that input. Probably unlikely, but something to consider while analyzing this issue.

Comment: @IInspectable same with low level mouse hooks. And also non low level keyboard/mouse hooks. If someone registers a hook after you, they get called first and can bypass the rest of the chain. If you want to ensure your hook gets called first, you could unregister and re-register it periodically.

Comment: @Anders, he reports that the screensaver runs as expected. I'm not sure if the screensaver infrastructure has anything to do with the GetLastInputInfo data (either directly or indirectly).

Comment: @IInspectable (and Remy): Thanks for the thoughts on filtering input. I doubt that this is what's happening, but I certainly see the possibility. I can adjust my low level logging accordingly.